# How to handle heavy query as light and fast version?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance, linq

I have been using Fetch Next (instead of linq query skip.take()) but below query extremely slow how can i handle this slow query. I wanna make it faster.

How to rewrite this sql query and linq version (if it is faster)

```
var ciftciDestekler = ctx.tblDestek.SqlQuery(
    " select d.ParselId,d.DestekId,d.Urun,d.KullanimSekli,d.TarimSekli,d.EkiliAlan,d.DesteklenenAlan,d.Aciklama,d.TarifeId,d.VeriSurumu "+
    "from tblCiftci c "+
    "inner join  tblParsel p  on c.CiftciId = p.CiftciId "+
    "inner join tblDestek d on p.ParselId = d.ParselId where c.UretimSezonu = 2016 "+
    "order by d.DestekId "+
    "OFFSET 0 ROWS -- skip 10 rows "+
    "FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY; --").ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to point that your query doesn't select only 10 rows - it **selects all rows**, because [FETCH NEXT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) part is optional and you have [commented it out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181627.aspx) with "-- skip 10 rows".

Your query is a huge single line without line breaks, so it is not actually:

```
select d.ParselId,d.DestekId,d.Urun,d.KullanimSekli,d.TarimSekli,d.EkiliAlan,d.DesteklenenAlan,d.Aciklama,d.TarifeId,d.VeriSurumu 
from tblCiftci c 
inner join  tblParsel p  on c.CiftciId = p.CiftciId 
inner join tblDestek d on p.ParselId = d.ParselId where c.UretimSezonu = 2016 
order by d.DestekId 
OFFSET 0 ROWS -- skip 10 rows 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY; --
```

But rather a:

```
select d.ParselId,d.DestekId,d.Urun,d.KullanimSekli,d.TarimSekli,d.EkiliAlan,d.DesteklenenAlan,d.Aciklama,d.TarifeId,d.VeriSurumu from tblCiftci c inner join  tblParsel p  on c.CiftciId = p.CiftciId inner join tblDestek d on p.ParselId = d.ParselId where c.UretimSezonu = 2016 order by d.DestekId OFFSET 0 ROWS -- skip 10 rows FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY; --
```

You should remove that comment or make it a [Slash-Star](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178623.aspx) comment that won't influence the following code.